# TabLayout и фрагменты

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Сделал TabLayout добавил фрагменты но вот проблема я никак не могу понять как с взаимодействовать с объектами в фрагментах, к примеру добавляю туда textInputLayout 
и я хочу сменить у него свойство Hint программно но если я пытаюсь что либо сделать во фрагменте то просто не получается за неимением findViewbyId а просто так не работает, или ещё для примера ни как не получается добавить событие OnClick для кнопки, события из фрагмента своего же он не видит а если из родительского активити то ругается:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ru.ifr0z.fabuserlocation.example, PID: 22565
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method fd(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button'
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:424)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:381)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6648)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6620)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:787)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26167)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:891)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7539)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:958)
```

Поэтому прошу у вас помощи, подскажите пожалуйста как правильно взаимодействовать с объектами во фрагментах, пытался гуглить этот вопрос но не нашёл ответа. Если не сложно киньте код с примерами пожалуйста или документацию где можно будет почитать обо всём этом. Заранее спасибо

Comment: У вас `android:onClick` в разметка для кнопки прописан, а метода подходящего не находится. Уберите из разметки и вешайте обработчик в коде.

Answer (score 0):

Как вам правильно сказали в комментарии - уберите атрибут onClick в xml у кнопки. И вообще забудьте, что он есть, это крайне неприятная штука, допустимая только для приложений уровня нажал на кнопку - фон поменял цвет.

Как вы сейчас создаете фрагмент? Просто если бы он у вас вообще хоть как-то работал, то вопроса про поиск вьюшки во фрагменте не должно было бы быть... Выглядеть должно так

```
    public class MyFragment extends Ftagment{

        public View onViewCreate(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
        }

        public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
            ((EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.text_input)).setHint("MyHint");
        }
    }
```

И вообще любые взаимодействия с элементами фрагмента должны происходить внутри фрагмента